# Watching model in a Service never catch any change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have been struggling with this (supposed to be) simple issue for several hours.

What I have got is: there is a provider that will watch the model changes then will update the database accordingly. Following is the code taken from the fiddle focused on the part with the issue.

```
this.$get = function ( ) {
            return {
                listen: function ( $scope, model ) {
                    if ( !that.enabled ) return;
                    $scope.$watch( function () {
                            return $scope.model;
                        },
                        function ( newValue, oldValue ) {
                            if ( newValue != oldValue ) {
                                // never gets to this line !
                                alert('Cool !');

                                // .. rest of the code to proceed with db updates
                            }
                        } );
                }
            };
```

check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yasarbayar/UG652/8/) for the working code.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Fiddle link isn't working

Comment: should be working now, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GC93C/).

The main issues were that:

1. `TestCtrl` was not registered to any module.  So, I wired it up by calling `TestModule.controller`.
2. You needed a deep watch on `model`.  So, now the watch has a third parameter (set to `true`).  This will watch into the properties of the `model` object.

Here is the full code:

```
var TestModule = angular.module( 'TestModule', [ 'AutoSaveP' ] )
.config( function ( autoSaveProvider ) {
    autoSaveProvider.enabled = true;
    autoSaveProvider.tablename = 'test';
    autoSaveProvider.primary_field = 'test_id';
} );

TestModule.controller('TestCtrl', function( $scope, $timeout, autoSave ) {
    $scope.model = {
        test_id: 1,
        first_name: 'john',
        last_name: 'doe'
    };
    $timeout( function () {
        autoSave.listen( $scope, $scope.model );
    }, 100 );
});

var AutoSaveP = angular.module( 'AutoSaveP', [ ] )
.provider('autoSave',
     function () {
        this.enabled = true;
        this.table_name = null;
        this.primary_field = null;

        this.$get = function ( ) {
            return {
                listen: function ( $scope, model ) {
                    $scope.$watch( function () {
                            return $scope.model;
                        },
                        function ( newValue, oldValue ) {
                            if ( newValue != oldValue ) {
                                // now gets to this line!
                                alert('Cool !');

                                // .. rest of the code the proceed with db updates
                            }
                        }, true );
                }
            };
        };
    });
```

Comment: I tried so many different ways (some were really stupid), but totally forgot about deep watch parameter (true). Learning can be a real headache sometimes. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to help.  I like this idea, BTW.  Might make a good public module if it could be made general. :)

Comment: Once I finish the module up and running, I can/will share it. Thanks for the encouragement :)